# How can I extract a json from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to extract json from a particular string which looks like this:

```
'loglocale=
{
    "seed": "pqr",
    "pageHashCode": "xxx",
    "timestamp": 1553589859880,
    "channel": "mobile",
    "serviceVersion": "1.0",
    "language": "en-CHN"
}
; regStatus=xx; s_dslv=34; s_fid=65-64748; s_vn=64678%26vn%3D1',
  groups: undefined ]
```

I have tried this but could not extract it .

```
var regex=cookies.match(/{"seed":(\w|\W)*"channel":(\w|\W)*}/);
```

What is the solution I could use?
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Is the leading `'` and stuff after the `;` actually part of the string? Do you have access to the actual JSON data? It's best to use `JSON.parse` rather than regex if possible. You could use `JSON.parse(s.match(/({.+?})/ms)[0]);` if the string is verbatim as in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know there is only a single plain JSON object like this in the string, you can use this regex to capture the curly braces and everything in between:

```
const curlyBracesInclusive = /\{([^}]+)\}/
const arr = string.match(curlyBracesInclusive)
// arr[0] will be a the JSON string, if one was found
```

This is no way guarantees the string is valid JSON. So if you want to run `JSON.parse` on the result, be aware it will throw an error if the string is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

For the loglocale:

```
let dataJSON = `
'loglocale=
{
    "seed": "pqr",
    "pageHashCode": "xxx",
    "timestamp": 1553589859880,
    "channel": "mobile",
    "serviceVersion": "1.0",
    "language": "en-CHN"
}
; regStatus=xx; s_dslv=34; s_fid=65-64748; s_vn=64678%26vn%3D1',
  groups: undefined ]`
```

then:

```
let string = dataJSON.substring(
       dataJSON.indexOf("loglocale=") + 10, 
       dataJSON.lastIndexOf("; regStatus")
   )
JSON.parse(string);
```